# Javascript getBoundingClientRect() - apply to multiple instances of class

Tags: javascript, jquery, getboundingclientrect

I've been trying to use a function to detect if an element is in the viewport:

```
function isElementInViewport (el) {
    var rect = el[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    return (rect.top>-1 && rect.bottom <= $(window).height());
}
var s= $('.special'),
    y = $('.status');

$(window).on('scroll resize', function(){
    if(isElementInViewport(s))
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(isElementInViewport(s))
            {
            var offer_id = s.data("offer-id");
          alert(offer_id);
            y.text('Yes');
        }
      }, 3000);
    }
    else
    {
        y.text('No');
    }
});
```

Unfortunately this only seems to work for the first instance of the class 'special'. How do I get it to apply to all instances of that class?

Note that I've added a 3 second delay, to prevent fast scrolling from triggering it.

Here's the jsfiddle of my progress: http://jsfiddle.net/azjbrork/6/

Comment: Well, why are you calling it on `el[0]` only if you want to loop over all elements in the collection?

Comment: @Bergi the function isn't mine. I'm a relative beginner in javascript trying to learn by practice...

Comment: `el[0]` is used because `el` is a jquery object - in this case `$('.special')` and `getBoundingClientRect();` is a pure js function that can only be called on the first component of the jQuery object. Hence `$('.special')` must become `$('.special')[0].....` . in this case `el[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using jquery `each` we can run the function on each instance of the `.special` class and report back accordingly (snippet below) :

```js
function isElementInViewport(el) {
  var rect = el[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  return (rect.top > -1 && rect.bottom <= $(window).height());
}
var s = $('.special'),
  y = $('.status');

$(window).on('scroll resize', function() {
  s.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (isElementInViewport($this)) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (isElementInViewport($this)) {
          var offer_id = $this.data("offer_id");
          // advise using an underscore instead of a hyphen in data attributes
          //      alert(offer_id); // reported in text below
          y.text('Yes : ' + offer_id);
        }
      }, 200);
    } else {
      //    y.text('No'); // omit this line otherwise it will always report no (subsequent out of screen divs will overwrite the response)
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.special {
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #f90;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
.status {
  position: fixed;
  right: 2em;
  top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class='special' data-offer_id='a'></div>
<div class='special' data-offer_id='b'></div>
<div class='special' data-offer_id='c'></div>
<div class='special' data-offer_id='d'></div>
<div class='special' data-offer_id='e'></div>
<div class='special' data-offer_id='f'></div>


<div class='status'></div>
```

Comment: Wow, amazing thanks for teaching me about 'each' I didn't know that!